# webcam Sunplus Integrated Webcam HD dont work ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam

My webcam is Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD and works fines in ubuntu 20.04  live cd. But after install ubuntu, the webcam don't works, she just turns on the light.
The most curious thing is that after entering the live cd again and restart for the OS installed, the webcam works! But after restart stop works again! Crazy!

My machine is a dell vostro.

The hwinfo --usb output:

```
06: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: MtLc.abYmUw330z0
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-6:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1bcf "Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc."
  Device: usb 0x2b99 "Integrated_Webcam_HD"
  Revision: "83.30"
  Driver: "uvcvideo"
  Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
  Device File: /dev/input/event11
  Device Files: /dev/input/event11, /dev/input/by-id/usb-CNFHH47O381420038CE0_Integrated_Webcam_HD-event-if00, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:6:1.0-event
  Device Number: char 13:75
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1BCFp2B99d8330dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (Hub)
```

Comment: Your title implies Ubuntu Core 20 or another 20 release; 20 is not 20.04, as the 20 is used only with *snap* only products.  You weren't specific by what 20.04 system; was it an ISO that boots & runs using GA kernel, but on subsequent boot is using HWE kernel stack?  if so switch to using the GA kernel.  You're light on specifics (is it a server ISO? desktop ISO you installed etc...)

Comment: Sorry. live and installed (Desktop 64bit) system are same version: 20.04